# Why do VCS changes disappear from the changes view when using IntelliJ 11 and Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 11.1 with the bundled HG plugin. When I change a file it appears in the changes view but disappears when I switch to another app. TortoiseHG still sees the change, i.e. 'hg status' shows the files, but IntelliJ just doesn't show it.

I have tried changing the configuration options but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was setting IntelliJ to monitor the repository root and not the source code root.